# Invalid prisma.user.findUnique() invocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I can't seem to find what the error in the invocation is

```
function findUser(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    
    prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { username: username },
        select: { username: true }
    })
    .then(data => {
        res.send({
            'userExists': data ? true : false
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
           message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving user."
        })
    })
    .finally(async () => { await prisma.$disconnect()});
```

```
// schema.prisma

    datasource db {
      provider = "postgresql"
      url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
    }

    generator client {
      provider = "prisma-client-js"
    }

    model User {
      id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
      username String @unique
      password String
      salt String
      createdAt DateTime @default(now())
      updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

From Prisma side everything is OK. The problem is probably `req.body.username`, if it's undefined you receive `Invalid 'prisma.user.findUnique()' invocation`.
You have to add validation for username, i.e.

```js
if {typeof username !== string} return res.status(404).send('invalid username')
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be the late response. I was also running into the same problem. But documentation saved my day. https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#findunique

You just have to add `@unique` attribute to your **username** field in **schema.prisma**, like below —

```
username String @unique @db.VarChar(255)
```

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. Add @unique and also re-run npx prisma generate

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code it seems that the username is missing from your req.body. I would suggest always verify the params you want to extract from req.body. I refactor your code to es6.

Here is the updated code you can try,

```
function findUser(req, res) {
    // Destructure username from req.body
    const { username } = req.body;

    if(username == null) throw new Error('Username undefined');
    
    // when property and value is same, you can write 'username' like below
    prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { username },
        select: { username: true }
    })
    .then(data => {
        res.send({
            'userExists': data ? true : false
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
           message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving user."
        })
    })
    .finally(async () => { await prisma.$disconnect()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the Database URL worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and this solved it in my case

not working:

```
        const projects = await prisma.project.findMany();
        return projects;
```

working:

```
        const projects = await prisma.project.findMany();
        if (projects) {
            return projects;
        }
```

Before the user creates projects, 'projects' will always be empty so returning it causes an error

Comment: What does "empty" mean exactly?

Comment: By empty I meant that its table(in my case 'project') doesn't contain any rows of data.

Comment: Then this `if` statement will achieve nothing